# Oracle doesn't Support TOP

Tags: sql, database, oracle

We cannot use `TOP` command in SQL in ORACLE to get the top n sorted rows,as it doesn't support it. But there are ways of getting the result using `rank()` and `rownum()` but that requires and inner query. I want to know if there is any other way apart from using `rownum()`/`rank()` with inner query.

Comment: Oracle 12c (http://www.oracle-base.com/blog/2012/10/06/oracle-openworld-2012-day-5/) will have FETCH FIRST and OFFSET. If you can wait that long... ;)

Comment: (I don't understand why it takes so long for certain products/environments to get "features that make developers happier" ..)

Comment: @pst having recently moved to using PostgreSQL instead of Oracle, I'd say that Oracle just have a different priority. The major audience for PostgreSQL to address with their upgrades is the development community, but for Oracle it is the business community at large, hence an emphasis on large-scale features and performance more than developer convenience.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Oh, I'm not saying not to have those "Enterprise Features" (which cost the $$$), but I'm saying - spend the fraction of the time required to make it *nice* to work with as well. (And Oracle has had *plenty* of money/resources/time to do this. Of course, the same can be said for a number of "Enterprise" product lines ..)

Comment: @pst It looks like from 12c they may be getting that message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "rownum()" is.  The best way is the answer that @PinnyM deleted . . .

```
select *
from (<your query here>
      order by <your ordering>
     ) t
where rownum < xx
```

This is *much* better than using `row_number()` or `rank()`, because `rownum` requires minimal processing for the value.

By the way, `TOP` is specific to SQL Server and Sybase.  Other databases using `LIMIT`.

Comment: It's still a sub-query (or to be precise a derived table) which the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The question says s/he doesn't want it with respect to `rownum()`.  I have no idea what that is.

Comment: I assume the OP means `row_number()` by `rownum()`